# How do I check if there are bad word in a string or not

Tags: php

This is my PHP code for replacing bad word in the string to *, it's working well.

But I want to check if in the string are bad word or not. How can I do this?

index.php

```php
<?php
include("badwords.php");
$content = "cat bad_word dog";
$badword = new badword();
echo $badword->word_fliter("$content");
?>
```

badword.php

```php
<?php
$bad_words = array (
    // an array of bad words here...
    );

class badword {
    function word_fliter($content) {
        global $bad_words, $wordreplace;
        $count = count($bad_words);
        for ($n = 0; $n < $count; ++$n, next ($bad_words)) {
            $filter = "*";

            //Search for bad_words in content
            $search = "$bad_words[$n]";
            $content = preg_replace("'$search'i","<i>$filter</i>",$content);
        }
        return $content;
    }
}
?>
```

............................................................................................................................................................

Comment: How do you want the output to be and what have you tried yourself? Try to be more thorough in your question, and show us what you have done already.

Comment: i want to detect my old string have bad word or not ?

Comment: So whats wrong with this code? Seems to work, https://eval.in/691288. You might want to use word boundaries so `glass` etc aren't stripped incorrectly.

Comment: yes, it's work good. but i want to knowmy odl string have bad word or not ?

Comment: So the question is "how to know when you `preg_replace` is tiggered?"

Comment: @mongkonPea the easiest way would be to compare the original string with the filtered one. though you should reflect about the use of all of this, since you can *not* even hope to come close to filter all bad words, and at some point inadvertently *will* filter some words that aren't bad. "pussy" for example is quite an usual term to call a cat & "bitch" a female dog, and defining "gay" as a bad word will make a whole community dislike you very much.

Comment: I think this started out and ending as a bad question; IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

edit: Since you wanted full code...
please note that i changed the function name from word_fliter() to word_filter()

index.php

```
<?php
include("badwords.php");
$content = "this is an example string with bad words in it";
$badword = new badword();
echo $badword->word_filter("$content");
if($badword->usedBadWords()){
    // do whatever you want to do if bad words were used
}
?>
```

badwords.php

```
<?php
$bad_words = array (
    // insert your naughty list here
    );

class badword {
    private $usedBadWords = false;

    function word_filter($content) {
        foreach($bad_words as $bad_word){
            if(strpos($content, $bad_word) !== false){
                $this->usedBadwords = true;
            }
            $content = str_replace($bad_word, '***', $content);
        }
        return $content;
    }

    function usedBadWords(){
        return $this->usedBadWords;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Without `foreach` loop: `$content = str_replace($bad_words, '***', $content);`.

Comment: TIL that str_replaces can take arrays as params :)

Comment: make $usedBadwords a private variable in the class badword. replace your for loop with my foreach loop (second example). create a second function in the badword class named usedBadWords or similar, in which you return the variable $usedBadwords. In the index file you can then call the new function to check if there were any bad words. (this call must be after you called the filter() function.

Comment: T__T could you please update your answer. i don't understansd

Answer (score 0):

This should work, you just check if it the `content` matches any bad words and returns it.

index.php

```
<?php
include("badwords.php");
$content = "cat bad_word dog";
$badword = new badword();
$return_val = $badword->word_fliter("$content");
echo $return_val['content'];
if($return_val['has_bad_words']){
  ..do stuff
}
?>
```

badword.php

```
<?php
$bad_words = array (
   // an array of bad words here...
);

class badword {
    function word_fliter($content) {
        global $bad_words, $wordreplace;
        $count = count($bad_words);
        $has_bad_words = false;
        for ($n = 0; $n < $count; ++$n, next ($bad_words)) {
            $filter = "*";

            //Search for bad_words in content
            $search = "$bad_words[$n]";
            $content = preg_replace("'$search'i","<i>$filter</i>",$content);
            if(preg_match("'$search'i", $content) && !$has_bad_words){
               $has_bad_words = true;
            }
            else {
               $has_bad_words = false;
            }
        }
        return array('content' => $content, 'has_bad_words' => $has_bad_words);
    }
}
```

Comment: no, if `preg_match` returns 1/true then you know `preg_replace` triggered.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Well, speaks for itself, but here it is

Comment: and bad_word array ?

Comment: it not get anything T_T do you test it before ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$bad_words = array (
    // an array of bad words here...
    );

$bad_word_check = "";
$bad_word_detect = "";

class badword {
    function word_fliter($content) {
        global $bad_words, $wordreplace;
        $count = count($bad_words);
        for ($n = 0; $n < $count; ++$n, next ($bad_words)) {
            $filter = "*";

            //Search for bad_words in content
            $search = "$bad_words[$n]";

            $xx = "%".$search."%";
            if(preg_match($xx, $content)) 
            {
                $bad_word_check = "1";
                $bad_word_detect = $bad_word_detect."".$search.",";
            } 

            $content = preg_replace("'$search'i","<i>$filter</i>",$content);
        }
        return array('content' => $content, 'bad_word_check' => $bad_word_check, 'bad_word_detect' => $bad_word_detect);
    }
}
$content = "cat bad_word bad_word dog association";
$badword = new badword();
echo $badword->word_fliter("$content")[content];
echo "<BR>";
echo $badword->word_fliter("$content")[bad_word_check];
echo "<BR>";
echo $badword->word_fliter("$content")[bad_word_detect];
?>
```

Comment: is this a solution you got from another answer? If it is, you should accept the one you got it from.

Comment: this makes no sense... I'm going home xD

Comment: @Cashbee I don't blame you one bit.